# Method Code Coverage not covering incase of calling flatMap() in Spring Reactor

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, code-coverage, reactor

First take a look inside the code

```
   public Mono<EmployeeDTO> getResponse() {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create("TEMP URL");

        Mono<Employee> employeeMono = client.get()
                .uri("temp url")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Employee.class);

        return employeeMono.flatMap(this::employeeMapper);
     }

    public Mono<EmployeeDTO> employeeMapper(Employee employee){
    //
    //
    //
    //
    }
```

I'm calling Code coverage in IntellijIDEA, all lines are covered but employeeMapper() unable in case of if I using Mono with FlatMap method.

I need to covered the employeeMapper(), please suggest me what should I need to do so that code inside the employeeMapper() also covered.

Please let me know in case you need more clarification.

Thanks in advance 
Yasir

Comment: Your code can't possibly compile, since flatMap expects a method that returns a Mono, not an EmployeeDTO. Given that the code doesn't compile, how could the test cover the code?

Comment: @JBNizet question updated

Comment: So, what is the code of the test? Does it subscribe to the Mono returned by getResponse()? If it doesn't, then nothing happens. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#reactive.subscribe